# Background working differently in the first run

Tags: backgrounds, auxiliary-files

Coming back to a document after some months caused the background configured through the `background` package to disappear. I checked it was recovered after deleting the `aux` file, but **only for the first run**. After a few tests, the background image was sometimes recovered but only for the last pages of the document, and others seemed (I can't reproduce it now) to run consistently for every run if `vshift` and `hshift` were set to zero. Is it just disappearing for the first run? Is the position being taken differently in the first run, making the background fall outside the page?

How can I make the position consistent from the first run?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[pages=all]{background}%
\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
color=black,
opacity=0.65,
angle=0,
vshift=0cm,
hshift=0cm,
contents={%
  BACKGROUND CONTENT
  }%
}


\begin{document}

Lipsum.

\end{document}
```

Overleaf is not showing this issue, I find it with Miktex, Texmaker, running PDFLaTeX.

Comment: that's normal, background uses page nodes, and they require two compilations to find the coordinates. In overleaf it works as it always compiles at least twice such a document.

Comment: That's surprising, then I can't understand how I did not notice it when adjusting positions in many documents. Maybe I used Overleaf to find values instead of running a full document locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `overlay` mode (no `remember picture`), tikz will place the origin at the current location (`\put`).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\put(0.5\paperwidth,-0.5\paperheight)% center of paper
  {\tikz[overlay]{\node[opacity=0.65] at (0,0) {BACKGROUND CONTENT};}}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

---

This version will work with XeLaTeX..

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox{\background}
\savebox{\background}{\begin{minipage}[t][\paperheight][s]{\paperwidth}
  \hrule height0pt\vfill
  \centering
  \tikz{\node[opacity=0.5]{BACKGROUND CONTENT};}
  \vfill\hrule height0pt
\end{minipage}}% Note, \hrule is used to put baselines at the top and bottom of the page.

\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\put(0pt, 0pt){\usebox\background}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: with pdflatex transparency should work. Did you use xelatex?

Comment: As it turns out, I **was** using xelatex.  Forgot to switch back to pdflatex.